# AppleScript to Rename file list to Specific Names

Tags: applescript, applications, automator, automation, macos

*I've spent hours researching this and I can't seem to find an answer, so your help would be greatly appreciated!*

I have an audio recorder that outputs 16 files that are always named the same.

**ORIGINAL FILE NAMES**

(TRK01.WAV, TRK02.WAV, TRK03.WAV, TRK04.WAV, TRK05.WAV, TRK06.WAV, TRK07.WAV, TRK08.WAV, TRK09.WAV, TRK10.WAV, TRK11.WAV, TRK12.WAV, TRK13.WAV, TRK14.WAV, TRK15.WAV, TRK16.WAV)

I want an Automator App that changes the file names to the following list.

**NEW FILE NAMES**

(01_Lav.WAV, 02_HH1.WAV, 03_Piano.WAV, 04_TR AC.WAV, 05_MX AC.WAV, 06_Bass.WAV, 07_ElectG.WAV, 08_KickD.WAV, 09_Vox1.WAV, 10_Vox2.WAV, 11_Vox3.WAV, 12_Vox4.WAV, 13_CrowdL.WAV, 14_CrowdR.WAV, 15_Aux7_R.WAV, 16_MainLR_R.WAV)

This way I can save the Application on a hard drive where I transfer the files to and run it when needed.

I was thinking it would go something like this:

```
set theFolder to choose folder

set name of file “TRK01.WAV“ to “01_Lav.WAV“
set name of file “TRK02.WAV“ to “02_HH1.WAV“
set name of file “TRK03.WAV“ to “03_Piano.WAV“
set name of file “TRK04.WAV“ to “04_TR AC.WAV“
set name of file “TRK05.WAV“ to “05_MX AC.WAV“
set name of file “TRK06.WAV“ to “06_Bass.WAV“
set name of file “TRK07.WAV“ to “07_ElectG.WAV“
set name of file “TRK08.WAV“ to “08_KickD.WAV“
set name of file “TRK09.WAV“ to “09_Vox1.WAV“
set name of file “TRK10.WAV“ to “10_Vox2.WAV“
set name of file “TRK11.WAV“ to “11_Vox3.WAV“
set name of file “TRK12.WAV“ to “12_Vox4.WAV“
set name of file “TRK13.WAV“ to “13_CrowdL.WAV“
set name of file “TRK14.WAV“ to “14_CrowdR.WAV“
set name of file “TRK15.WAV“ to “15_Aux7_R.WAV“
set name of file “TRK16.WAV“ to “16_MainLR_R.WAV“

tell application "Finder"
    (open theFolder) select
end tell
```

How would this actually be done?

Comment: Is this a one time thing? If yes, I'd just do it in **Terminal**. First _change directories_ to where the files are, e.g. `cd "/path/to/files"` and then copy an paste the following into the **Terminal** _window_ and press enter:

Comment: `mv TRK01.WAV 01_Lav.WAV; mv TRK02.WAV 02_HH1.WAV; mv TRK03.WAV 03_Piano.WAV; mv TRK04.WAV "04_TR AC.WAV"; mv TRK05.WAV "05_MX AC.WAV"; mv TRK06.WAV 06_Bass.WAV; mv TRK07.WAV 07_ElectG.WAV; mv TRK08.WAV 08_KickD.WAV; mv TRK09.WAV 09_Vox1.WAV; mv TRK10.WAV 10_Vox2.WAV; mv TRK11.WAV 11_Vox3.WAV; mv TRK12.WAV 12_Vox4.WAV; mv TRK13.WAV 13_CrowdL.WAV; mv TRK14.WAV 14_CrowdR.WAV; mv TRK15.WAV 15_Aux7_R.WAV; mv TRK16.WAV 16_MainLR_R.WAV`

Comment: No It’s something that I need to do on a regular basis.  Often several times in one setting.  That’s why I’m trying to make an Automator workflow or application.  

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Well you could still use it in an **Automator** _Service_ as shown in the linked image: https://imgur.com/a/ZEH67Nu This is set so in **Finder** you select the target folder containing the WAV files and run the _service_ on it.

Answer (score 1):

*– user3439894, Thanks for the Help!  This got me really close!*

For anyone who needs to do the same thing, here's what I did to make it work. In my circumstance, I needed an application, so I can save it on a hard drive and use it on whatever Mac I'm working on at the time.  I didn't need another service to clutter up my menus.

**Here's how it's done:**

1) Using Automator, create a "new document" type: "Application"

2) Insert "Ask for Finder Items" box and select Type: "Folders".

3) Insert "Get Selected Finder Items" box (below "Ask for Finder Items" box)

4) Insert "Run Shell Script" box.  Set Shell: "/bin/bash" set Pass input: "as arguments".

5) Type:

```
cd "$1" || exit 1

mv TRK01.WAV 01_Lav.WAV 
mv TRK02.WAV 02_HH1.WAV 
mv TRK03.WAV 03_Piano.WAV 
mv TRK04.WAV "04_TR AC.WAV" 
mv TRK05.WAV "05_MX AC.WAV" 
mv TRK06.WAV 06_Bass.WAV
mv TRK07.WAV 07_ElectG.WAV
mv TRK08.WAV 08_KickD.WAV
mv TRK09.WAV 09_Vox1.WAV
mv TRK10.WAV 10_Vox2.WAV
mv TRK11.WAV 11_Vox3.WAV
mv TRK12.WAV 12_Vox4.WAV
mv TRK13.WAV 13_CrowdL.WAV
mv TRK14.WAV 14_CrowdR.WAV
mv TRK15.WAV 15_Aux7_R.WAV
mv TRK16.WAV 16_MainLR_R.WAV
```

Save the Application to desired location and you're done!